# mongodb with nodejs(npm mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my application i have to store data to mongodb using nodejs(npm mongodb). I have installed mongodb , nodejs and npm mongodb but the problem here is I installed them in  separate folders. I am unable to organize  the directory structure properly that's way I am getting errors.If you tell me the folder structure it will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how to make a [package.json](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html)? `npm init` will give you a good starting point. After that, `npm install` is your friend. See [guide](https://npmjs.org/doc/developers.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try mongoose - `npm install mongoose`, mongoose is a ODM for mongodb.
API Documentation - http://mongoosejs.com/

Short example from official documentation:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('localhost', 'test');

var schema = mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string' });
var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', schema);

var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
kitty.save(function (err) {
  if (err) // ...
  console.log('meow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm install mongodb` command in your application directory. For example, nodejsapp folder  is the application directory.
The folder structure inside the directory will look like :

```
    nodejsapp
    ├───────────  node_modules <-- All the node modules installed using npm comes here --> 
    |                ├──────────── .bin
    |                ├──────────── express
    |                └──────────── mongodb
    ├───────────  app        <-- holds all our files for node components (models, routes)--> 
    ├───────────  config     <-- all our configuration will be here -->
    ├───────────  public     <-- holds all our files for our front-end application -->
    ├───────────  server.js  <-- Node configuration -->
```

The `node_modules` folder is created when you use `npm` command in the application directory.           
 This is a better way to organize the node packages for a project.